# Subview with UIButton isn't clickable

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
UIButton *mainButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[mainButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mainButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0f, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0f);
[self.view addSubview:mainButton];

UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 100)];
[subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[mainButton addSubview:subView];

UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
secondButton.center = CGPointMake(subView.frame.size.width/2.0f, subView.frame.size.height/2.0f);
[subView addSubview:secondButton];
```

Why is the mainButton clickable but the secondButton isn't?

Comment: frame of main button is 100 by 100 and subview is more then that. So second button is going out. But exactly what you are trying to do with this?

Comment: when to add the subview in self.view then both button will clickable

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement this. I'm making a UIView subclass that will have a UIButton that when pressed will present a selection bar to the right of the mainButton with even more buttons on it to select from. And this DID work. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: You guys actually answered the question for me, so thanks a bunch : D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K you should add sub view on self.view.

```
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 100)];
[subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[self.view addSubview:subView];

UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
secondButton.center = CGPointMake(subView.frame.size.width/2.0f, subView.frame.size.height/2.0f);
[subView addSubview:secondButton];
UIButton *thirdButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100)];
[secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
secondButton.center = CGPointMake(subView.frame.size.width/2.0f, subView.frame.size.height/2.0f);
[subView addSubview:secondButton];
```

try this. it will add two buttons on subview.

Comment: I need both buttons to be on different subviews to work with the way I'm doing things

Comment: in target methode of main button add buttons (2/3...) to subview and add subview to self.view.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it Durgaprasad... instead of putting the subview 'sliderView' and it's containing buttons to the parent UIButton I could make the 'sliderView' part of the UIMultiButton subclass and call [[theMultiButtonSubclass parentView] insertSubview:sliderView belowView:this] or something

Answer (score 0):

you should not add UIView as subview in UIButton

TRY this

```
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 100)];
[subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[self.view addSubview:subView];

UIButton *mainButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[mainButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mainButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0f, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0f);
[subView addSubview:mainButton];

UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];
[secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[subView addSubview:secondButton];
```

EDIT: If you want to keep both buttons on different views then take two sub views and try like.....

```
UIView *subView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];
[subView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[self.view addSubview:subView1];

UIButton *mainButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[mainButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[subView1 addSubview:mainButton];


UIView *subView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 100)];
[subView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
[self.view addSubview:subView2];


UIButton *secondButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleShape.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[subView2 addSubview:secondButton];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need them to be on different subviews

Comment: your welcome see the EDIT i have made to the answer this might be helpful to you... Enjoy coding....!!!!!!!!

Comment: Wonderful! And I will enjoy coding : D As always

Comment: Unfortunately although this method works it wasn't what I needed. I'm subclassing a UIButton to have UIButtons of it's own

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your subView is a child of the mainButton. You should add it to the viewController's view instead.